# Prevent Archive URLs

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, archives

My Wordpress site goes looking for an archive page if I append a year after the URL.

For example: `http:/mysiteurl.com/my-site/2018`. If there are posts from this year, it ends up redirecting to `index.php` for some reason. If there are no posts from that year, it goes to 404 page which is what I want. For example: `http:/mysiteurl.com/my-site/2014` goes to a 404 page because there are no posts from that year, which is what I want.

My permalink structure is set to **Post name** which is like this `http:/mysiteurl.com/my-site/sample-post/`. So typing a year after the URL **should** display a 404 page, **not** show me archives.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress generates date archives automatically, it's just a thing it does. You see the `index.php` template probably because there isn't a more specific one for date archives in your current theme. There are plugins that disable these archives, Yoast SEO is one.

A quick fix is to empty the date archive rewrite rules:

```
add_filter( 'date_rewrite_rules', function( $rules ){
    return array();
} );
```

Visit the **Settings > Permalinks** page after adding this to flush rules.

Comment: This works! I don't know why it does that when I set my permalink structure to "Post name". I thought if there's no page or post named "2018" then it should show the 404 page. Thanks for the help! (also I have registered some Custom Post Types if that makes a difference but they all have `has_archive => false`)